# In a responsive site design, how do i put a list below other list that contains a sub-list without overlap the main lists

Tags: html, css

I have lists with sub-lists and I need that when window screen shrinks the lists that go below the others don't overlap the first ones sub-list.

**HTML markup -**

```
         <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul>    
               <li class="menulinks">.....</div>
                 <ul>
                     <li class="submenulinks"><div>.....</div></li>
                 </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**CSS -**

```
.sitemap .menulinks{
    background-color:green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height:35px;
    width:11%;
    float:left;
    min-width: 100px;
    display:block
}
submenulinks{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    color: green;
}
```

Desired Output in small screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0ss1.jpg
[image]

Existing :
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLhuR.jpg

Comment: share your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple : remove the fixed height of your li.menulinks, add a "header" (green rounded rectangle with 35px height) div as first child of the li and...you're set !

Look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/32pga/

```
<div class="sitemap">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <ul>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 6</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 7</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 8</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 6</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 7</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 8</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 6</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 7</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 8</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 6</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 7</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 8</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 6</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 7</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 8</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 6</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 7</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 8</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulinks">
                <div class="menulinks-header"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 1</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 3</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 6</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 7</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 8</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenulinks">
                        <div>Test 9</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.sitemap .menulinks {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width:11%;
    float:left;
    min-width: 100px;
    display:block;
}
.sitemap .menulinks-header {
    height:35px;
    background-color:green;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.submenulinks {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    color: green;
}
```

If you give a fixed height of 35px to your li.menulinks element, you're explicitly saying to the layout engine that there is room to render element just below the green rounded rectangle - in other words, 35px below the top of your li.

Note that the children of your li elements are displayed as overflow. Should you add "overflow:hidden;" declaration to your li.menulinks, the children would not be rendered.

Let the layout engine compute the height of your li elements by itself by not giving them a height.